# How to delete the data from the Azure application insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, purge

I want to delete the traces data from my application insights table. Can one tell me how do i do that.

I'm following the below article from microsoft,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/components/purge

I'm trying to pass the below Request body,

```
{
"table": "traces",
"filters": [
{
  "column": "timestamp",
  "operator": ">",
  "value": "2017-09-01T00:00:00"
}
]
}
```

[image]

I'm getting Response Code: 202, but i'm still seeing the data in the analytics, where i query traces.

Please let me know, how i can delete the data with traces on my application insights resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197397/application-insights-purge-data-from-custom-data-source):

Yes, it is possible to purge Application Insights data, **but it may take a while (e.g. 2-3 days) for the operation to complete.**

So please wait:)

Answer (score 0):

For traces delete operation you would need to use the separate table name as "Traces" in the body of purge operation. then you can check the status using get purge status REST API operation. Refer to know more - https://sanganakauthority.blogspot.com/2019/06/how-to-delete-or-purge-azure.html