# Powershell script to Purge data for application insight which is enable to log analytics

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-application-insights

My application insight is enabled to Log analytics. I want to delete logs from specific application insight..

I want a PowerShell script where I can purge the data which is attached to workspace..

Comment: What's keeping you from writing this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

> I want a PowerShell script where I can purge the data which is
> attached to workspace..

Based on our research , we haven't find any Power Shell cmdlets that can be used to  purge the data of application insights.

You can invoke this [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/components/purge) from PowerShell & you can send a POST request with a body that contains the Application Insights telemetry table we want to purge and the filter that we want to apply on those records.

Below are the steps to followed to invoke the rest api using the PowerShell & to purge data of a specific column :

- To use this API , You need to create an app registration in AAD &
  create client secret for that app registration.
- you need to assign a role to your app in order to access the Application Insights resource.
- Select the Application Insight resource (or directly select the
  Subscription object if you want), click on Access Control (IAM) and
  then add a role assignment.
- create a new role assignment with `Data Purger` as the role and select your app registration (search for the
  app name)

**Here is the PowerShell script to Invoke the REST API:**

```
Import-Module AzureRM.Profile

##pass the app registration details
$appId = "YOR_APPLICATION_ID"
$key = "YOR_CLIENT_SECRET" 
$tenantId = "YOUR_AAD_TENANT_ID"

$subscriptionId = "YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
$resourceGroupName = "YOUR_APPINSIGHTS_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME"
$resourceName = "YOUR_APPINSIGHTS_INSTANCE_NAME"

# Create the authentication URL and get the authentication context
$authUrl = "https://login.windows.net/${tenantId}"
$AuthContext = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext]$authUrl

# Build the credential object and get the token form AAD
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential -ArgumentList $appId,$key
$result = $AuthContext.AcquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/",$credentials)

# Build the authorization header JSON object

$authHeader = @{
'Content-Type'='application/json'
'Authorization'=$result.CreateAuthorizationHeader()
}

$URI = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/${resourceName}/purge?api-version=2015-05-01"

$body = @"
{
   "table": "customEvents",
   "filters": [
     {
       "column": "timestamp",
       "operator": "<",
       "value": "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000"
     }
   ]
}
"@


$purgeID=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Method POST -Headers $authHeader -Body $body
```

It may take a while (e.g. 2-3 days) for the purge operation to get  complete.

For more information , you can refer [this](https://demiliani.com/2021/03/30/deleting-application-insights-telemetry-data-on-demand-with-powershell/) blog or this reference [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197397/application-insights-purge-data-from-custom-data-source) thread.

Comment: this above is for application insight data. according to Microsoft we cant purge the data of application insight which is enable to log analytics. but my application is enable to log analytics and their in workspace so many application insight is attached but i want to delete only one application insight data.. is their any way please share with me